# why sleep in nodejs doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, sleep

I use this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep) to sleep inside a loop, my loop look like this

```
while(condition){
    usleep(1)
    while(condition){
        usleep(1)
        // ... do stuff (sync)
    }
}
```

althought i'm sleeping only for 1us, the loop never terminate it just take very very long time, but when i remove the sleep statement, it just run and done.

I'm trying to sleep to make the CPU calms down and not use 100% so the server keep accepting other requests!

Using setTimeout inside a loop is not a good idea, because setTimeout is async.

I thought using recursion, but i'm afraid it will be too slow, i'm iterating arount 100000

Comment: Please tell me this is not production code, I would suggest trying to figure out why your CPU is constantly burning 100%.. What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: could you check the console for the `sleep: using busy loop fallback` message? if it is present the module falls back to `while...` loop blocking

Comment: why not use setTimeout?

Answer (score 3):

Sleep blocks the current thread, so this effectively will not help you try to accept other requests.  You can try something like [sleep-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep-async) to do the job.

Comment: this still won't fix his problem of using too much CPU.

Comment: funny enough this doesn't look like the answer but it is.  You can't sleep to allow other requests in node because node is single threaded in its default configurtaion, which is what the OP is trying to do.  Nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to keep that code the way it is now, use Promises and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). That way your application won't be blocked for other requests.

Something like this for you to start:

```
async function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

async function run() {
    while(condition){
        await sleep(1000);
        // ... do stuff
    }
}

run().catch(err => console.error(err));
```